# get NSDate into titleForHeaderInSection from another ViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios5, tableview

I have two views, first one is with calendar and the second one is a UIView with a  `tableView`;
I'm trying to display the selected date from the firstView. Managed to get the selected date inside `ViewDidLoad` method of my secondView.

How I add my `NSDate` to my `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method?

Comment: I think you need to create variable in nextview and set it as a title for table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *displayDate;` (or `strong` instead of `retain` when using ARC) on your TableViewController (dont forget to synthesize). The first view can then set the property of the TableViewController, for example:

```
MyTableViewController *mtvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
mtvc.displayDate = selectedDate;
...
```

You can then access the date from within your TableViewController using `self.displayDate`, for example in your `titleForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: but my ViewController in which I have the table View its a UIView controller

Comment: Basically the same thing. Somewhere you have to have a `UITableViewDataSource`, that class gets the property and gets the NSDate passed.

Comment: `@interface secondView : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` this is my header line of the 2nd view Controller

Comment: So the view controller is the data source. Then again you can create the property in your UIViewController.

Comment: Just like in the post, put the `@property` in your UIView's .h file, put a `@synthesize displayDate;` in the .m file. Whereever your first view creates an instance of the `secondView`, fill the `displayDate` property as shown in the code. Your `secondView` now can use `self.displayDate` anywhere in the class to access the date. Put a `self.displayDate = nil` in your `dealloc` method of `secondView` to avoid a memory leak.