# Objective-C selectively populate table from plist; if key equals

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, plist

plist1 is an array of 40 dictionaries, with 4 strings each.
plist2 is also an array, but of 120 dictionaries with 2 strings each.

If I list all the teams in a hockey league in a table (populated from a certain key in plist1), say I choose the fifth one down. This pushes a new table. The 120 dictionaries in plist2 have two strings - each has one for a year of the league's history in order, and one for who won the championship that year. I want this second table to list only the years for which the the dictionary's second key is the same team name that was just selected in the first table, plist1. So, when I select team "5" from the first table, I'd expect to see only the years that team "5" won in the second table. The idea is that all the years will be present in plist2, but the irrelevant ones will be blocked in the actual table on-the-go.

How can I say "if the user selected team X, then show the years just for team X, not all the years."

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do this kind of filtering quite nicely using `NSPredicate`:

```
NSDictionary *testA = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"valA", @"key1", @"1", @"key2", nil];
NSDictionary *testB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"valB", @"key1", @"2", @"key2", nil];
NSDictionary *testC = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"valC", @"key1", @"1", @"key2", nil];
NSDictionary *testD = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"valD", @"key1", @"3", @"key2", nil];

NSArray *testArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:testA, testB, testC, testD, nil];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key2 == %@", @"1"];
NSArray *testFilter = [testArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

NSLog(@"%@", testFilter);
```

This setup creates 4 dictionaries and an array of them. The filter expression now searches for all contained objects where `key2` is equal to `1`, which should be `testA` and `testC`. And voila theres the output:

```
2011-11-24 18:57:07.822 testapp[9977:f803] (
        {
        key1 = valA;
        key2 = 1;
    },
        {
        key1 = valC;
        key2 = 1;
    }
)
```

This way you can create a predicate to filter by your team name and create a filtered version of your array. Generally this works on all kinds of object that support key-value coding (which `NSDictionary` does, further info on that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170)

Comment: Thank you for the response!
Is there any way I could use my existing array in the plists instead of creating new dictionaries in the code? Perhaps I could call them up...? I did this with the first table by doing this:


`- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ChronoWSH" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSArray* tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 self.chronologicallyArray = tmpArray;
 [tmpArray release];`

then

`cell.textLabel.text = [[self.chronologicallyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:YEAR_KEY];`

Comment: Of course, the dictionaries were only there to create examples. In your code you would start at the NSPredicate line and use the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` directly on your own plist array.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. The last thing I don't quite get is `@"key2==%@", @"1"];`
What do I put in there to ensure that the program loads the right string, as the string will vary by team. It would have to be a variable. Would I have to set it up by saying that key2 is the team's name, and that key2 must equal the string of the name? I'm rather inexperienced, thanks for your patience.

Comment: `key2` is the key used in the dictionary for filtering. I assume your dictionary is set up in a way that theres a key named like "teamname" and a key "year" with the appropriate values. Then you would put `teamname` instead of `key2` and you can use a variable for the team name to be filtered instead of the constant `@"1"` in my example.

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, I'm just unsure as to how to define that variable. Do I have to create an NSString for didSelectRowAtIndexPath and then plug in that NSString as my variable?

Comment: If I understand you app concept correctly you would pass the team name being selected form the first view controller (the list of teams) to the second view (the filtered list by team name). The filtered list view controller would then in its `viewDidLoad` method create a filtered copy of the array and store it locally based on this variable, much like you do this in your first table in the comment above. The filtered view controller now has its own filtered list and can show this straightforward as if there were no other list.

Comment: I think you do understand it correctly, but can you give me an example of actually passing the name from one view controller to another? Just actually creating a variable for the selected team and then incorporating that into the new table is beyond me. Sorry!

Comment: No problem, I outlined the steps in another thread for passing an NSDate object between view controllers. Maybe this is help enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258735/get-nsdate-into-titleforheaderinsection-from-another-viewcontroller/8258801#8258801

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still a little confused. In my first TableViewController, I have the team array (alphabeticallyArray) defined in the .h and synthesized in the .m. I also have an array called selectedTeam that has an @property and is synthesized.

`DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.alphabeticallyArray = selectedTeam;`

Comment: I've just changed it a little, if you haven't read the above comment disregard it:
`AlphabeticallyTableViewController *alphabeticallyTVC = [AlphabeticallyTableViewController alloc];
    alphabeticallyTVC.alphabeticallyArray = selectedTeam;`
The DetailViewController is what I'm calling the second table controller.

Comment: You could always load you array in the second view. but you do need the team name as NSString property. Assuming you declared and synthesized a property `teamName` and `dataArray` in your detail view. In your `viewDidLoad` something like this:
`(void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"secondFilePlist" ofType:@"plist"]; NSArray* tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; self.dataArray = [tmpArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"teamname == %@", self.teamName]]; [tmpArray release];``