# iOS: Isolate string in plist based on two keys

Tags: ios, key, plist

In my iOS app, I am loading a list of teachers into a tableview from a plist, and it's working great.

In another plist I have a hierarchy of Root Array > Dictionary > four Strings, then more Dictionaries with the same Strings.  This is for a school, so the keys are the "ClassName", the "Period", an irrelevant number, and the "Teacher" name.  Each teacher has multiple classes a day, some with the same name but at a different period.

SO HERE'S THE PROBLEM:
Based on the selection of the teacher from the tableview (saved in NSString), and also the period (saved in NSString), I need to get the name of the class being taught.

Example: I select ***Bob Smith*** at ***8 AM***, and it returns that he is teaching ***Algebra***.

I need to then export that result to a string, that's not the hard part.

This is the same general idea of this
[Objective-C selectively populate table from plist; if key equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260693/objective-c-selectively-populate-table-from-plist-if-key-equals)
but checking TWO keys, and that code is not working for me.

I have looked extensively on stackoverflow and other sites with no good results.

Your help would be so much appreciated. You guys rock.

EDIT: more info
This is in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
NSArray *listOfClasses = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"periodTchrCls" ofType:@"plist"]];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Teacher == %@", cellText];
NSArray *testFilter = [listOfClasses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

NSLog(@"This is the test %@", testFilter);
```

"cellText" is the selection of the teacher's name.
The plists are loading fine.
The log shows

```
This is the test ( lots of space      )
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show your predicate code and what it results in.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, I found an answer.

The major hidden problem was that the teacher names either had a ghost space added to them, or didn't have a period after their middle initial in one of the plists.

Thanks for your help.

Here's my code for anyone who wants it.

```
NSArray *listOfClasses = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"periodTchrCls" ofType:@"plist"]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Teacher == %@) AND (Period == %@)", cellText, testLabel.text];

NSArray *filter = [listOfClasses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSString *nameFromArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [filter valueForKey:@"ClassName"]];
```